# Reducing the Shape of a 3 dimensional array to 2 dimension array or a DataFrame but nesting the entries of an axis as a list in the other axis

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, numpy-ndarray

So I am having Issues parsing a dataset. I have an array of dimension **axbxc**.. I want to convert it to a 2 dimensional array or preferably a **DataFrame** where the shape is **axb[c]** meaning i want the entries of c as a list under the different columns of **b** where **a** indicates the number of rows just as shown below.

[Image showing my desired output or DataFrame1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8jz.png)

Comment: have you try multiindex dataframe before?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to make dataframe from 3d array, so Iam using multiindex for this case.
If I have data like this:

```
data = np.random.random((3,4,5))
```

First, i will make index for the dataframe like this:

```
#for index DataFrame
array1 = np.arange(0,3)
array2 = np.arange(0,4)
iterables = [array1.tolist(),array2.tolist()]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
```

then I create the dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(3*4,5),index=index)
```

and the result:

```
>>> df
                     0         1         2         3         4
first second                                                  
0     0       0.824310  0.504847  0.524925  0.864275  0.737136
      1       0.568694  0.349271  0.413173  0.256493  0.062059
      2       0.247119  0.433598  0.916364  0.579064  0.749974
      3       0.404534  0.951233  0.511670  0.147814  0.662542
1     0       0.982126  0.914015  0.093291  0.756780  0.610224
      1       0.853450  0.463260  0.712753  0.874551  0.118973
      2       0.365568  0.822954  0.883047  0.398301  0.496278
      3       0.329698  0.929337  0.085680  0.312687  0.210055
2     0       0.973088  0.131381  0.943814  0.596567  0.248843
      1       0.986318  0.631151  0.671049  0.123051  0.362313
      2       0.109261  0.008249  0.129571  0.702480  0.786857
      3       0.426099  0.322008  0.260797  0.435768  0.453475
>>>
```